# Android App rejected for Violation of the Prohibited Actions provision of the Content Policy

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, hybrid-mobile-app

Just i'm created playlist in Youtube which contains the all upcoming tamil movies trailers and

accessing that playlists in my app using below API with help of AJAX.

https://gdata.youtube.com/feed...

Once i got the playlist,displaying the movie trailers as list.

When user click any trailer, just I'm plying the video in WebView help of YouTube IFRAME API.

$scope.playVideo = function() {

```
        if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
            window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function() {
                $scope.loadPlayer();
            };
        } else {
            $scope.loadPlayer();
        }
    };

    $scope.loadPlayer = function() {
        $scope.player = new YT.Player('TTvideo', {
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
            videoId: $scope.vId,
            playerVars: {
                'controls': 1,
                'autohide': 1,
                'rel': 0,
                'showinfo': 0
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': function() {
                    AppItem.stopLoader();
                }
            }
        });
    };

    if ($scope.player && $scope.player.d && typeof $scope.player.destroy === 'function') {
        $scope.player.destroy();
    }

    $scope.playVideo();
```

But my app rejected because of below reason by google:

we have determined that your app enables background playing of YouTube videos, which is a violation of the YouTube API Terms of Service:

I never displaying any background video.

Please help me

Comment: What did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your implementation of the WebView makes the video continue playing while the app is closed, this is what they mean by `background playing`