# How to disable YouTube background playing in Cordova Android?

Tags: android, jquery, angularjs, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to stop the YouTube video playing when I lock my mobile.

I tried almost each solution provided in SO but issue still persist.

[How to pause YouTube video on InAppBrowser when my Cordova app goes to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835308/how-to-pause-youtube-video-on-inappbrowser-when-my-cordova-app-goes-to-backgroun)

[PhoneGap keep running on Android after onPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21505369/phonegap-keep-running-on-android-after-onpause)

[How to disable youtube background playing in phonegap android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39610560/how-to-disable-youtube-background-playing-in-phonegap-android?rq=1)

[How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview/25380464#25380464)

[My app got rejected from google play due to some issue with network policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38045639/my-app-got-rejected-from-google-play-due-to-some-issue-with-network-policy/43566373#43566373)

[How do I fix this: app enables background playing of YouTube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244808/how-do-i-fix-this-app-enables-background-playing-of-youtube-videos?rq=1)

[App enables background playing of videos, cordova issues, google play rejecting apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31320749/app-enables-background-playing-of-videos-cordova-issues-google-play-rejecting?rq=1)

I have added the below code in confix.xml.

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false" />
```

**HTML and Angular Code**

```
  <script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!--    <script src="./js/angular-youtube-embed.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="./js/angular-youtube-embed.js"></script>
```

**Angular**

```
var ProfileApp = angular.module('ProfileApp', ['youtube-embed']);
$scope.$on('youtube.player.ready', function ($event, player) {
  $rootScope.YTPlayer = player;
});

<div ng-style="{'display':youtubevideo == ''?'none':'block'}">  
                                            <iframe title="YouTube video player"
class="YouTube-player" type="text/HTML" width="350" height="194"
                                                    ng-src="{{getIframeSrc(youtubevideo)}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
                                        
<youtube-video video-url="youtubevideo" player-width="'350px'" player-height="'194'" allowfullscreen></youtube-video>
```

Some JS code to detect pause event.

```
 <script>
    document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
  if ($rootScope.YTPlayer) {
    $rootScope.YTPlayer.stopVideo();
   //or maybe $rootScope.YTPlayer.pauseVideo();
  }
}, false);
    </script>
```

You can see I tried both approach iframe and YouTube API but none of them are working. How can I stop the YouTube video playing?

Comment: Have you already tried to put this pause-event-listener into a "deviceready"-listener? Like in [this](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html) example.

Comment: Another issue is that you try to access the rootscope outside angular/ionic: You can get the root-scope via [angular.element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24596251).